# Area Doesn't show Object when goes to shading

Tags: shaders

I got a little question here about my problem.
So recently I try to follow some tutorial on YT and it goes to the part when it's time to do shading. But when I go to shading, the area where you can see the object doesn't show anything except some blurry area *see the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Maybe try zooming out like in layout mode?

Comment: THANKS ! that really solve it

Comment: With the object selected in the outliner, numpad '.' (period)